# Having An Audio Recorded In An Specified BPM

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio

I am using the `recorder.js` for recording couple of audio elements(output sound) that are playing in the page. I wonder how I would be able to set a number, as the BPM(Beats Per Minute) of the recorded audio.

```
//connectRecorder Function
function connectRecorder() {
    if (audioSources == '') {
        audioContext = new AudioContext();
        gainNode = audioContext.createGain();
        for (var i = 0; i < audiosClass.length; i++) {
            audioSources.push(audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audiosClass[i]));
            audioSources[i].connect(gainNode);
        }
        gainNode.connect(audioContext.destination); 
    }
}

//recordButton Click Handler
function recordButtonClickHandler() {
    if (recordButton.value == 'Start Recording') {
        recorder = new Recorder(gainNode);
        recorder.record();
        recordButton.value = 'Stop Recording';
    } else {
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.exportWAV(function (blob) {
            hiddenRecordExportLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            if (recordSelect.value == 'wav') {
                hiddenRecordExportLink.download = 'record.wav';
            } else {
                hiddenRecordExportLink.download = 'record.mp3';
            }
            hiddenRecordExportLink.click();
        });
        recordButton.value = 'Start Recording';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the BPM, specifically, but you can set the playback rate.  If you know your source track is 120 BPM, and you want to bring it up to 130 BPM, you would set the playback rate like this:

```
audio.playbackRate = 130 / 120; // 1.083333
```

Comment: I don't want to change the BPM. I want to have my file recorded in a specified BPM. Also, the BPM of source track(s) is not specified. actually, I want something like loading a couple of audio sample(s) on Ableton Live drum rack(the bpm would not change) play and record with specified BPM. The BPM of the audio sample(s) is not specified but the recording is.

Comment: @AliAhmadi Audio isn't recorded with any particular BPM.  There's a fixed sample rate, and that's it.  Ableton Live keeps track of BPM and cue points in a separate metadata file.  On playback, it changes the playback rate to line up with the desired BPM.

Comment: Can I do this with JavaScript? I mean ' keeps track of BPM and cue points in a separate metadata... '.

Comment: Sure.  You could just write it out as JSON if you wanted.